# make box with borders, divides in html

Tags: html, css

hello i want to make box in html and inside it i want to add slanted divider line. how can i do that?

I want to make exactly as of this image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EBDZJNHxtQxwDctjL239hMDjiEW4w48W

I did upto this but is isnot being aligned as of the picture.

```html
<div class="box">
      <p style="text-align: left;"><u>प्रेषक</u><br><br>देवका अर्याल <br>लुम्बिनी पुस्तक पसल <br>बुटवल-८, रूपन्देही <br>लुम्बिनी, नेपाल</p>
      <p style="text-align: right;"><u>प्रापक</u><br><br>श्रीमान् महाप्रबन्धक <br>साझा बिक्री कक्ष <br>भृकुटी मण्डप, काठमाडौं, नेपाल</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this help you!

```css
.box {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #fff, inset 0 0 0 8px #000;
  width: 100%; /* The width you want. */
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box::before {
  width: 1px;
  content: "";
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 4px;
  transform: skew(45deg)
}
.box .leftSide {float:left;}
.box .rightSide {float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="leftSide"><u>प्रेषक</u><br><br>देवका अर्याल <br>लुम्बिनी पुस्तक पसल <br>बुटवल-८, रूपन्देही <br>लुम्बिनी, नेपाल</div>
  <div class="rightSide"><u>प्रापक</u><br><br>श्रीमान् महाप्रबन्धक <br>साझा बिक्री कक्ष <br>भृकुटी मण्डप, काठमाडौं, नेपाल</div>
</div>
```